# How to automatically generate comments in Visual Studio 2010 and C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

From Eclipse I'm used that when I start typing a comment for a class or method, the parameters, return types and exceptions are autogenerated. But in VisualStudio 2010 I can't find something like this. Any hints how to achieve that?

Comment: Note that, in C#, "exceptions" are typically not commented, since they aren't defined at the method level like in Java...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is on the line right above your method just type "///" and it will generate a comment template based on the method.

Comment: That'll teach me for writing my comments before I write the method, so that I am focussed on what I intend the method to do!

Comment: But that does not include Exceptions. Would be very nice if it could create a summary of all exceptions and we could delete the ones that we catch. By specifying them manually I often forget to comment some of them wich is awful, especially in libraries used by other people.

Comment: Used to be: 3 forward-slashes then a TAB. Doesn't seem to work VisualStudio.17.Release/17.7.1+34009.444.

Answer (score 14):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) is a free extension that will do this.  Just hit (by default) Ctrl+D anywhere within a method, and it will add XML Documentation comments with defaults filled in (though they typically should be modified/expanded).

Comment: Just want to note: Free for personal use only. In case you care ;-)

Comment: Isn't Free anymore its now Nagware

Answer (score 10):

Use "///" instead of "//" for comments. For example, the following comment was auto-generated by just starting to type "///":

```
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="terms"></param>
public TVec(IEnumerable<Term> terms)
{
}
```

Comment: ''' for anyone wanting to do this in visual basic :)

Answer (score 3):

Try typing "///" one line ahead of a method. Tell me if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ghostddoc to generate alot of your xml comments:
http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

I think there is a free version available.